# Spring MVC post List of ImmutablePair with Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a service method that takes `List<ImmutablePair<Long, Long>>` but can't get the controller to accept (bind? my jargon isn't great) the data. Simplified version of what I currently have:

Object:

```
public class Dto {
    private List<ImmutablePair<Long, Long>> foo;

    ...getters and setters

}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "list", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public String postInventoryList(@RequestBody Dto dto) {
    ...
}
```

JS:

```
$http.post(listUrl, JSON.stringify({foo: [{left:1, right:1}]})).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

I can get it to work if I pass the pairs differently, but I'd really like to just use `ImmutablePair` to keep things clean and avoid having to process the data before calling that method. I'm guessing I need to tell Spring how to deal with this object type? How would I do this? Thanks!

Edit:

If I use this class instead of the ImmutablePair everything works fine. I just don't want to have to do this.

```
public class Pair {
private Long left;

private Long right;

public Long getLeft() {
    return left;
}

public void setLeft(Long left) {
    this.left = left;
}

public Long getRight() {
    return right;
}

public void setRight(Long right) {
    this.right = right;
}
}
```

Comment: Try to add index to each entry, for example, {foo[0]: [{left:1, right:1}]},foo[1]:[{left:1, right:1}])....

Comment: That definitely won't work.

Comment: What's `ImmutablePair`? Is it from Apache?

Comment: Are you having any error?

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair I think the problem is that it's not a POJO and Spring doesn't know how to deal with it. I think I need to make a custom binder but I can't find any info on how to do this.